# xcode returns error that Alamofire is not signed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am working on a small app that uses the `Alamofire iOS framework`. Upon trying to use the IPA file that I generate, it throws:

> error 0xe8008019

saying this:

> Alamofire.framework does not have a valid signature

How exactly can I fix this? Selecting the `Alamofire.xcodeproj` from the left file view tab and filling in the Team option doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: How did you added Alamofire?

Comment: I opened my project, then dragged Alamofire.xcodeproj to the left inside of xcode where it shows the app files, changed it's compatability to 9.3 and then I I added "Import Alamofire" to my code

Comment: You should consider using an dependency management, for example cocoapods.It seems that your framework is not bundled when you try to deploy it as ipa.

Comment: Even after using cocoapods the issue is still there.

Comment: You should go with Pods!